# How does a PHP client communicating with a Java Program via Sockets/RPC retrieve new results without a page refresh?

Tags: java, php, ajax, sockets, rpc

I am using `Apache Thrift` to communicate between a `Java` program and a `PHP` client.

Lets say the Browser-based/User Facing `PHP` client runs

```
<?
//Thrift RPC protocol stuff

$result =client->javaMethod();

echo "This is the newest $result";

?>
```

Let's say I want the `$result` variable to be updated every `X` seconds, is there some `AJAX` like way of doing this? It'd be nice to use `Thrift` since its one solution that works across multiple languages...

I'm guessing a `"sleep"` every `X` seconds is a bad idea for `memory` reasons?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this script running from the command line or via browser?

Comment: via browser....edited question to reflect that.

Comment: Then an AJAX polling script would be your best choice. it'd be a new connection/rpc call each time, since your PHP script would eventually run into max_execution_time territory at some point.

Comment: I thought AJAX only worked if the client was receiving JSON/XML as the response from an HTTP call?

Comment: AJAX is just a fancy word for Javascript doing an http request in the background without forcing a full page refresh as you get when you submit a form the normal way. As far as the server-side scripts are concerned, there's pretty much NO difference between an AJAX call and a regular form submission. JSON is the preferred method of returning data for an AJAX call, but nothing says you can't return a blank page as well, or plain text, or xml (the X in ajax, actually). It comes down to whatever's easiest for your script to process when the request completes.

Comment: i guess my main point is about the HTTP request....i don't think the RPC/Socket based Thrift service communicates over HTTP

Comment: Shouldn't matter, since the RPC call will go out from your server to the service host. For the browser->server, the AJAX call will done via HTTP. Remember, the PHP executes on the server, NOT the client.

Comment: I see...basically by AJAX i make an HTTP request to the PHP client as often as I want..and the PHP client executes whatever its supposed to execute...regardless of format that the JavaMethod returns..Thanks!...mind adding as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a timed AJAX call to ping your server, which then executes the RPC call and returns its results. More details in comments above.